# MacBook Pro: lidwake value ignored?

Tags: macos, sleep-wake, pmset

I have a Mid-2014 Macbook Pro Retina running OS X 10.5.5. Unfortunately, I dropped it one too many times, and one of the display hinges has become very stiff. In fact, if I close the lid and then let go, it will spring open about an inch.

This is a problem, but worse is the fact that this wakes my Mac up, draining the battery. I'd like my Mac to go to sleep when I close the lid, but ignore opening the lid, only waking up when I press a key.

Obvious answer: the [`lidwake`](http://www.macworld.com/article/1055527/nowakelid.html) value. So, I used `sudo pmset -a lidwake 0` to set it to zero, closed the lid (it went to sleep), and opened the lid again, anticipating a continued black screen. Wrong, Chucko: it woke up. (Rats.)

On the theory that the settings might not take effect until a reboot, I rebooted. Nope: still wakes on lid opening.

Here's my current pmset settings:

```
mbpe:~ griscom$ pmset -g
Active Profiles:
Battery Power       -1
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standbydelay         10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                0
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        3
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 acwake               0
 lidwake              0
mbpe:~ griscom$
```

Any idea why a `lidwake` value of 0 is being ignored? Did support for this end at some point in Mac OS development? How can I keep my Mac from waking up when the lid opens?

Comment: When you close the lid place it on the table lid downwards... :)

Comment: @SolarMike Thanks, I'm doing that when I can, but it doesn't always work (e.g. when I put it in my bag).

Comment: The real solution will probably be to get the hinge(s) sorted out .